# Convergence of a sequence and its limit

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $\{v_n\}$ be a sequence defined by $v_1=1$ and 
$v_{n+1}=\sqrt{v_n^2 +(1/5)^n}$, for $n\ge1$. Then find limit of the sequence $\{v_n\}$.
I have found that the given sequence is monotone increasing but failed to find the limit.
Please help me to solve it.

Answer (score 11):

If I have read your question aright, then
$$v_{n+1}^2=v_n^2+\frac1{5^n}.$$
So
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}v_n^2=1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{5^n}.$$
You can sum this geometric series and take its square root to get the limit you seek.

Comment: Thank you. Good idea. @Lord Shark the Unknown

Comment: @Iamdark If Lord Shark's answer answers your question, you should accept it.

Comment: @AlgorithmsX It is a good idea to wait some time. Maybe other user provide answers that pleases Iamdark more.  Also it gives other user the chance to check the answer. At least  two or three days are absolutely reasonable.reasonable.

Comment: @miracle173 Fair enough.